# Matlab Maxima Minima Function

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, minima

So I'm a couple of steps away from successfully writing this function:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
function a=myanalyzecp(f,a,b)
syms x;
v=coeffs(f(x)); % grabs function's coefficients
vertex=(-v(2))/(2*v(3)); % vertex formula 
if (a<vertex && vertex<b)
    if (diff(diff(f(x)))>0) % f''>0 means minima
        a=1;
    else
        a=-1;
    end
else
    a=0;
end
```

The problem I'm running into is when the function only has 1 or 2 terms, such as x^2 or x^2+4 or x^2+4*x. Because then my vertex function fails

Comment: According to your "vertex" formula, `a=v(3), b=v(2), c = v(1)`. Is that right?

Comment: Right. I was hoping matlab would take, say, x^2 and

    coeffs (x^2) = [0,0,1], however it's simply 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *obtain all coefficients including zeros*, use [`sym2poly`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym2poly.html) instead of `coeffs`:

```
v = sym2poly(f(x));
```

That gives the result as a `double` vector, not as a `sym`. If you need it to be a `sym` you need to convert:

```
v = sym(sym2poly(f(x)));
```

Comment: Perfect, this was the function I needed versus coeffs, thanks soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Since `v` may contain one or two elements only, add a test, for instance

```
if length(v)==1, 
   vertex = ... 
elseif length(v)==2
   vertex = ...
else
   vertex=(-v(2))/(2*v(3));
end
```

This should replace `vertex=(-v(2))/(2*v(3));`

Comment: along with all my other if elses :(

Comment: @ADH See my edit - you should leave the tail of your program (the test regarding the position of the vertex wrt a,b) alone

Comment: I see, but there are 2 cases when length(v)==2, when it's x^2 and an x term; or x^2 and a constant. Does this matter?

Comment: @ADH I don't know, that's a math problem but if there are different conditions just add another if/else subclause within the `length(v)==2` clause to address the two possibilities. Point is after this if/else tree you should come out with one value of vertex.

Comment: alright, a lot more if else's than I'd like and expect for this question, but I'll give it a go